# Solo Caret vs. Caret with greedy optional character

Tags: regex

What is the difference of using just a `^` compared to `^.*` in regex pattern?

Seems `^` alone can be a valid pattern (not just an anchor).

Test result on JSFiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/wLvx0mus/4/

Comment: Show us an example. The `^` can be a few different things depending on the context. It can be [String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Literal Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), or [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

Comment: Many users show regex examples using regex101. [Here is an example of what I think you are asking.](https://regex101.com/r/zU7kG4/1)

Comment: Seems to me that I can use just a caret (the shortest option) to represent "any", then why use ^.* (longer).

Comment: The carot `^` asserts the position at start of a line in this case. (String anchor). The thing about the .* is that it is `greedy`, so it will match everything, as much of as possible (so including everything at the start, middle, and end of your string). So doing a regex for `.*` will return the entire string you are searching for. As this doesn't make sense, we need an example in order to tell you anything. The difference between ^ and ^.* is what else is happening in the rest of your regex.

Comment: The carret is an anchor, you can read more about the carret and other anchors here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html

Comment: Example: /^/.test('anything string') will return true. Seems like it's being treated as a complete pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `/^/` is a valid pattern.  It will match any string it's applied to, so it's no good for searching, validating or extracting text, but it is useful for replacing:

```
result = subject.replace(/^/mg, "gronk");
```

That will add `gronk` to the beginning of every line.  Whereas this:

```
result = subject.replace(/^.*/mg, "gronk");
```

...will replace the contents of every line with `gronk`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using it as the beginning of string character, one matches the beginning of a string, the other represents 0 or more characters of any kind starting at the beginning of the string

In substitution, the first one would effectively prepend your replacement value, while the other one would replace everything with your replacement value.

However, if you are using the `^` in a character class, it could be a negative match flag (e.g. `[^.*]` should represent any character that is not a literal `.` or `*`).  In any case, it's very difficult to provide a useful answer without knowing the context of how it's being used in your case.  Also, please provide the regex flavor you're using.  The difference in syntax could have a big impact.